# Is this mold situation ok to ignore?

Tags: attic, mold

We just bought a home in the North-East and were told by the home inspector that we had some mold growth in the attic, but that he didn't think it was the "toxic" black kind so it wasn't urgent, but we should get it checked out at some point. We got a 2nd opinion who agreed and in fact said some people just live with it.

We had a mold test done to confirm and my understanding is that it concurred with what the home inspector said. It was mold, but not the worst kind.

**Main House Air Test:**

Aspergillus penicillium = 14 raw - 560 count / m3

Cladosporium = 5 raw - 200 count / m3

Ascospores = 6 raw - 240 count / m3

**Attic Sheathing Bio-Tape:**

Cladosporium: "Very Heavy"

He estimated it would cost $3,000 to remediate.

We then passed his remediation plan onto local mold remediation companies who quoted us $5,000 - $8,000! And that is just for the mold, does not include installation of an attic fan to prevent future growth or new insulation.

I want to be responsible with our health and the health of our house, but this feels like a crazy amount of money for a relatively low amount of everyday mold.

Is it irresponsible to do nothing?

Comment: I'd pay more attention to curing the ventilation or moisture ingress - stop it from getting worse, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Every stick built house has mold of some type. I have worked in construction since the 70’s and well as a gopher 60’s , I currently work in a lumber mill , the boards are sprayed with a fungicide , plywood when I worked in that plant I could not believe how fast the “mushrooms” and other fungus grew on the edges of the veneer prior to being assembled. So don’t panic , proper ventilation is needed, high moisture can cause mold growth even with concrete structure. If there is real mold issues up there make sure soffit vents are clear and a ridge vent is clear I have not seen many metal vents get plugged but it can happen.

Comment: Yes!  Spend the money putting in a ridge vent or a gable vent attic fan.  Make sure you have good clearance for air flow to the soffits if not add baffles.

Answer (score 0):

The following site has good information.  Generally the thought is that air tests are often worthless without the interpretation from the person who administered the test.  What was their advice?  Are they both the tester and the re-mediator?

Given your numbers are all sub 500 and the categories for mold numbers start at 50,000 per m3 - I think this air test is saying you have low mold levels in your air.

"Normally in a building that has been cleaned or has never had a water intrusion and indoor mold problem, we expect airborne mold spore counts from a properly-conducted test to be in the few hundreds of spores per cubic meter of air or less"

https://inspectapedia.com/mold/Airborne_Mold_Count_Number_Guide.php